# Apply CSS to all rows of a table other than the one on which I'm hovering

Tags: html, css

Here's ma code:

```
table.main-menu tr:hover td {
color: #654321;
}

table.main-menu tr:hover img.icon {
width:100px;
}

table.main-menu tr:hover h2.title {
font-size:2.5rem;
}

table.main-menu tr:hover p.subtitle {
font-size:1.2rem;
}

table.main-menu tr:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

For each of these elements, I would like to apply special effects on all tr on which I'm NOT hovering, while I'm hovering on one of them. Example: if I'm hovering on row1, I want row2 and row3 to shrink, but when I'm not hovering on anything, they all go back "to normal".

Can I do that with CSS?
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your HTML Code too. This will help us to resolve your problem specifically. This also helps us to know your coding pattern so that we can give you an answer in that pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hovering a row means you're also hovering the table itself. With that in mind, you can combine with the `:not()` pseudo-class selector:

```css
table:hover tr:not(:hover) { /* Shrink styles */ }
tr:hover { /* Hovered row styles */ }
```

**A word of warning:** changing the size of content might cause the rows to shrink in height, meaning they will move up, and your cursor might then not be on the row you intended to hover.